# Consecutive Unity Crashes - [Unity Crash Log]

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, stack-trace, crash-reports

As the title says, my Unity project keeps crashing whenever I build an app for Android, and I'm not sure what's the cause. The crashes are inconsistent, sometimes it builds, sometimes it crashes. Here is the Unity crash log: https://sharetext.me/6qsszytlzp

I'm using Unity version is 2020.3.38f1 Personal.

I've tried restarting the computer multiple times. I've tried reading the crash log but I am unable to make heads or tails of what its saying.

Do let me know if I'm missing something!

Comment: Please provide Unity version and whole crash log. It's not possible to guess the issue with these lines

Comment: Sure, I've updated my post with a link to the full crash log and the Unity version

Comment: The notepad is empty to the link. Anyways please check this if this patch helps you a bit https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unity-crashes-when-calling-marshal-dot-getfunctionpointerfordelegate-on-a-delegate-with-a-nullable-return-value

Comment: Modified the link because someone deleted my crash log :) It should be accessible now